# strip all but the first element of an object with jq

Tags: json, filter, key, jq

Assume I have a json structure like:

```
{
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : 3
}
```

I want the same structure, but with only the first element:

```
{
  "a" : 1
}
```

I don't know or care what the name of the key is. I just want the first one. (Bonus points for being able to grab an arbitrary *n*th one.)

How do I do this with `jq`?

---

If I *did* know the name, this would be easy:

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '{a}'
{
  "a": 1
}
```

Which is a shortcut for:

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '{a: .a}'
{
  "a": 1
}
```

### Working, but terrible, solution

In trying to come up with a bunch of examples for what I've tried that didn't work, I finally came up with this thing that does work:

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '{(keys|first):.[(keys|first)]}'
{
  "a": 1
}
```

but that cannot possibly be the best way to do this.

Notably, the "shortcut" doesn't work:

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '{(keys|first)}'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ':' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{(keys|first)}
jq: 1 compile error
```

This also works, but is barely better, if not worse:

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '(keys|first) as $i | {($i): .[$i]}'
{
  "a": 1
}
```

(The "shortcut" doesn't work here, either.)

##### WTF?

Also, if I don't use parens around the `$i` as the key, craziness happens that I don't understand at all:

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '(keys|first) as $i | {$i: .[$i]}'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
(keys|first) as $i | {$i: .[$i]}
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 1:
(keys|first) as $i | {$i: .[$i]}
jq: 2 compile errors

% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '(keys|first) as $i | {$i}'
{
  "i": "a"
}
```

### Other stuff that doesn't work

```
% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq 'first'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number

% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq 'first(.)'
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}

% echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq 'first(.[])'
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you say

> I was just hoping for something more like `.[0]`

If you don't like the piping from the other solutions, then how about using string interpolation:

```sh
jq '{"\(keys_unsorted[0])"}'
```

```json
{
  "a": 1
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/frKSLMHNbW)

Note that all of your original attempts used `keys` which provides the keys in **alphabetical order**. For the sample data this makes no difference but I assume you were actually looking for the first key in **representation order**, for which you need to use `keys_unsorted`.
If I am wrong, then my answer translated to `{"\(keys[0])"}` should just work fine as well.

Comment: This is really interesting, but I don't understand it at all. What is the syntax here? I don't think I've seen `\(` at all.

Comment: Also, I don't really care about the order of what gets chosen. I'm really just cutting my input down for testing. Thanks for the detail, though.

Comment: @wfaulk This essentially is equivalent to what you called "shortcut" when failing with `{(keys|first)}`. Apart from using `keys_unsorted` instead of `keys` as explained above, and `[0]` instead of `|first` which should also be obvious, the trick here was to provide the key name as a string (basically `{"a"}` instead of just `{a}`), and generating that string using [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29) (everything between `\(` and `)` will be evaluated in the current context, stringifyied and embedded into the surrounding string).

Comment: Still not "happy" about having to explicitly grab a key name, but I think that this is probably as close as I'm going to come, and potentially the most readable. (BTW, it's the documentation that [refers to that syntax as a "shortcut"](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectConstruction:{}).)

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_entries`, `from_entries` and an index of your choice.

In the single-element syntax you need to wrap it in an array

```sh
jq '[to_entries[0]] | from_entries'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pn8pKqADfG)

In the range-syntax you need to additionally providde the to-index (which is one higher than the from-index if you want just 1 element):

```sh
jq 'to_entries[0:1] | from_entries'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PVRMmGfKjh)

Output:

```json
{
  "a": 1
}
```

Comment: It certainly works. Possibly better than what I came up with. But it still feels like there ought to be a simple filter for this, and that's what I was hoping for.

Comment: @wfaulk Simplified it.

Comment: Mine seems "wrong" because I have to actually grab the name of the first key and use it (twice, even) instead of just grabbing the first one. Yours seems "wrong" because I shouldn't have to convert the whole structure just to convert it back. (Though I was surprised to discover that it doesn't seem to have a significant impact on processing time on my actual big input.)

Comment: @wfaulk Do you have alternate variations of input are you considering here? if so update all your cases to propose a more generalized solution

Comment: @Inian My real-world object contains other objects instead of just ints, and, recursively, about half a million values. But that shouldn't make any difference to a general solution to the problem.

Comment: @pmf To be clear, I'm not denigrating your solution. It may be the best possible answer. I was just hoping for something more like `.[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jq's streaming parser, which might actually make sense if the input object were huge.

```
# counting from 1
# e.g. 2 | nthRun(1,2,2,3; .) #=> 2,2
def nthRun(s; f):
  . as $n  
  | label $out
  | foreach s as $x (null;
      if . == null then [1, ($x|f)] 
      elif .[1] == ($x|f) then . 
      else .[0] += 1 | .[1] = ($x|f) 
      end;
      if .[0] == $n then $x 
      elif .[0] > $n then break $out 
      else empty
      end);

fromstream(1|nthRun(inputs; .[0][0]), [[null]] )
```

Invocation example:

```
jq -nc --stream -f program.jq input.json
```

For the record, assuming the first key's value is atomic, you could simply write:

```
jq -nc --stream 'fromstream(input, [[null]])'
```

The same `nthRun` can of course also be used to access the n-th key-value pair in the same way.  More generally, it can be used without using the --stream option, e.g.:

```
def firstKeyValue:
    fromstream(1|nthRun(tostream),[[null]]);
```

Comment: I had no familiarity with the streaming mode beyond its existence, so it took me a while to wrap my head around. To summarize, streaming mode presents the filter with one leaf value at a time. The `-n` tells it not to automatically read anything, and `input` reads the first leaf value. The additional `[[null]]` adds an end marker to the stream representation of that first leaf value to make it a valid full stream. As you say, though, this only works when the first key has only a single leaf value behind it, which isn't sufficiently general for my problem. I learned something, though!

Comment: Updated to make it clear that the technique can be used quite generally.